# Why are my meteor settings not being passed to the application?

Tags: meteor, meteor-helper

```
set METEOR_SETTINGS={"public": {"stage": "development"}}
meteor
```

Then this line:

```
console.log(Meteor.settings.public.stage);
```

causes this error:

```
W20150612-20:45:38.338(-7)? (STDERR) TypeError: Cannot read property 'stage' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand the environment variable is only for the deployment mode (running a bundle).

In development, i.e., when running `meteor`, you need to use the `--settings` command line parameter to specify a file containing the settings.

Comment: I doubt it, because if I assign this environment variable to a malformed json, meteor does not start. I'll check though

Comment: Unbelievable, but true! Meteor checks the environment variable, makes sure it's a well-formed json, and ignores it. --settings 1

Comment: Unbelievable but true. Meteor makes sure the environment variable is correct and then ignores it if it is. --settings work. Thank you

Comment: I now feel stupid. I am new to Meteor, and I thought you run "meteor" in production. I looked around a bit, and meteor bundle some say is deprecated, and some say it is not; what's the proper way to run Meteor in production and why? What are the costs of running the development version in production?

Comment: You are right, `meteor bundle` is deprecated, it's now called `meteor build`. But other than that that's still the way to deploy if you run on your own server. The created tarball contains a readme with everything you need to know to run it.